# How to display a layer with graduated colours including null values?

Tags: arcmap, symbology

I performed add join and need to display my layer with graduated colours (null values included). I am able to do it in ArcGIS Pro (see below), but unfortunately I cannot find this option (shows values out of range) in ArcMap. I wanted to change null values to 0 but it doesnt not let me do it. How can I do it? Is there any workaround?

[image]

Comment: change null value to 0 is not possible in the joined table ( field from a join are not editable) but you should be able to do it in the original table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by excluding Null values form the classification, and setting a symbol for excluded values.

On the layer's *Symbology* tab for Graduated Colors, click the *Classify* button, and then click *Exclusion*.

Set the query to `MyField Is NULL`, and on the *Legend* tab, check *Show symbol for excluded data*, select a symbol and a label.

[image]

This is my test layer:

[image]